# PHP code cause to slow down my page

Tags: php, html

Good day, this is my first time posting here. my page takes too long to responds when I insert a PHP code:

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Administrators WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         session_register("myusername");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: index.html");
      }else {
         $error = "Your User Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: You can use `microtime()` to measure the time between codes. However, it seems that the only possible line that is slow, is the `mysqli_query()` line. Is your MySQL server remote / local?

Comment: header("location: index.html"); - add exit(); after so no other codes will be executed after the redirection.

Comment: @Raptor yep my server is local only

Answer (score 0):

- Way to measure executing time:

  - Insert `microtime(1);`before each part you want to measure;
  - print the real time each part took and analyse the reason;
- Suggestions:

  - get the content of $sql and add `EXPLAIN` before it, run the whole query in mysql to see if it cost too much time.
  - For example, `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Administrators WHERE username = 'myusername' and password = 'mypassword';`
  - Avoid SELECT *, use SELECT user, pass(parts you need) instead.